# Post Chrome Extensions don't do anything

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I've been practicing with NodeJS and RESTful APIs, and after a few days I've decided to try with Chrome Extensions.

I've got a form (Chrome Extension) and I want to send the data using HTTP POST to my server through the REST API.

I've followed this [tutorial](http://markashleybell.com/building-a-simple-google-chrome-extension.html)

The problem is that the following code doesn't do anything. 
I don't know why. I've followed the tutorial above, but nothing happens... no console.log, nothing...

Anyone can help me, please??

Here's my code:

popup.js

```
function postLink() {
event.preventDefault();

var postUrl = 'http://url.com:port';

var statusDisplay = null;

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST', postUrl, true);

var torrentUrl = encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById('link').value),
    params = "url=" + torrentUrl;

    console.log("torrentUrl -> " + torrentUrl);

params = params.replace(/%20/g, '+');

// Set correct header for form data 
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");

console.log("params -> " + params);

xhr.send(params);

// Handle request state change events
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() { 
    // If the request completed
    if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
        statusDisplay.innerHTML = '';
        if (xhr.status == 200) {
            // If it was a success, close the popup after a short delay
            statusDisplay.innerHTML = 'Downloading!';
            console.log("Everything is alright!");
            //window.setTimeout(window.close, 1000);
        } else {
            // Show what went wrong
            statusDisplay.innerHTML = 'Error: ' + xhr.statusText;
            console.log("Ooouch! U.u");
        }
    }
};

// Send the request and set status
//xhr.send(params);
statusDisplay.innerHTML = 'Preparing...';
}

document.addEventListener('load', function(evt) {
    statusDisplay = document.getElementById('status-display');
    document.getElementById('postForm').addEventListener('submit',   postLink);
});
```

popup.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Link</title>
<script src="popup.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <form id="postForm">
        <input type="text" id="link" name="link" placeholder="link" size=40><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        <span id="status-display"></span>
    </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

manifest.json

```
{
"manifest_version": 2,
"name": "LinkExtension",
"description": "BlaBlaBla",
"version": "0.1",
"browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
},
"permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "http://*/*",
    "https://*/*"
]
}
```

Comment: Check the console for errors by right-clicking the browser action and selecting "Inspect popup"

Comment: Use the Inspect Popup trick to open the console, then set a breakpoint at the top of the postLink function.  Then use window.location.reload() from within the console to reload the page, and you can debug it.